# Multiple curves in the same ParametricPlot3D as functions of different variables

Tags: plotting

Can two parametric curves as functions of different parameters be plotted in the same `ParametricPlot3D` without `Show`? Currently it throws an error "[some number] is not a valid variable" (plot4 in the code below). The curves separately can be plotted (plot2, plot3 in the code below). `Show` can display the two in the same plot.

```
Clear[d1, d2, q1, q2, pi1, pi2, p1br, p2br, cdf, c1, c2, p1, p2, \
\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], br1, br2, pi1opt, pi2opt, plot1, plot2, \
plot3]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < q1 < q2 && 0 <= c1 <= c2 && c1 <= p1 < p2 && 
   c2 <= p2 < \[Beta]*q2 && (p2 - p1)*q1 >= p1*(q2 - q1) && 
   p1 < q1*\[Beta] && 0 <= \[Alpha] < \[Gamma] < \[Beta];
cdf[v_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, 
     v < \[Alpha]}, {(v - \[Alpha])^2/((\[Beta] - \[Alpha])*(\[Gamma] \
- \[Alpha])), \[Alpha] <= 
      v < \[Gamma]}, {1 - (\[Beta] - 
      v)^2/((\[Beta] - \[Alpha])*(\[Beta] - \[Gamma])), \[Gamma] \
<= v <= \[Beta]}, {1, v > \[Beta]}}];
d1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = Max[0, cdf[(p2 - p1)/(q2 - q1)] - cdf[p1/q1]];
d2[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = 1 - cdf[Max[p2/q2, (p2 - p1)/(q2 - q1)]];
pi1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = (p1 - c1)*d1[p1, p2, q1, q2];
pi2[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = (p2 - c2)*d2[p1, p2, q1, q2];
\[Alpha] = 0; \[Beta] = 1; \[Gamma] = 0.5; q1 = 1; q2 = 2; c1 = 0; c2 \
= 0.5;
br1[p2_] = br1[p2_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], p1]
br2[p1_] = br2[p1_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pi2[p1, p2, q1, q2], p2]
pi1opt[p2_] = 
 pi1opt[p2_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], p1]
pi2opt[p1_] = 
 pi2opt[p1_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], p2]
plot2 = ParametricPlot3D[{p1, br2[p1], pi2opt[p1]}, {p1, 
    c1, \[Beta]*
     q1}
   , 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], Subscript[\[Pi], 
 2]}];
plot3 = ParametricPlot3D[{br1[p2], p2, pi1opt[p2]}, {p2, 
    c2, \[Beta]*q2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], Subscript[\[Pi], 
     1]}];
plot4=ParametricPlot3D[{{br1[p2],p2,pi1opt[p2]},{p1,br2[p1],pi2opt[\
p1]}},{p1,c1,\[Beta]*q1},{p2,c2,\[Beta]*q2}](*empty plot, "not a \
valid variable"*)
```

Comment: If `br1[p2_] = br1[p2_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[...]` and similar are intended to be [`memorization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) you have the syntax wrong. It would be `br1[p2_?NumericQ] := br1[p2] = NArgMax[...]`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon! That was my intention indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Perhaps this makes more sense:

```
ClearAll[path1b, path2b, prjbr1, prjbr2]
path1b[p_?NumericQ] := ConditionalExpression[{p, br1@p, pi1opt[p]}, c2 <= p <= β q2]
path2b[p_?NumericQ] := ConditionalExpression[{br2@p, p, pi2opt[p]}, c1 <= p <= β q1]
prjbr1[p_?NumericQ] := ConditionalExpression[{p, br1@p, 0}, c2 <= p <= β q2]
prjbr2[p_?NumericQ] := ConditionalExpression[{br2@p, p, 0}, c1 <= p <= β q1]

ParametricPlot3D[{path1b[w], path2b[w], prjbr1[w], prjbr2[w]}, 
 {w, Min[c1, c2], β*Max[q1, q2]}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({##, Directive[Dashed, #], Directive[Dashed, #2]} & @@  
    (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2})), 
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[P, 1], BR1[Subscript[P, 2]]}, ","], 
   Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[P, 2], BR2[Subscript[P, 1]]}, ","], 
   Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[π, 1], Subscript[π, 2]}, ","]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[path1, path2]
path2[p_?NumericQ] := {br2@#, #, pi2opt[#]} & @ Rescale[p, {c2, β*q2}, {c1, β*q1}]
path1[p_?NumericQ] := {p, br1@p, pi1opt[p]}

ParametricPlot3D[{path1[w], path2[w]}, {w, c2, β*q2}]
```

[image]

Showing the best response functions as projections:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{path1[w], path2[w], Append[path1[w][[;; 2]], 0], 
  Append[path2[w][[;; 2]], 0]}, {w, c2, β*q2}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({##, Directive[Dashed, #], Directive[Dashed, #2]} & @@ 
    (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2})), 
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[P, 1], BR1[Subscript[P, 2]]}, ","], 
   Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[P, 2], BR2[Subscript[P, 1]]}, ","], 
   Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {Subscript[π, 1], Subscript[π, 2]}, ","]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant. To check that I understand what is happening (to modify in the future): `{br2@#, #, pi2opt[#]} &` defines a function for one curve in 3D. The `Rescale` stretches it before it is assigned to `path2`. (Vaguely, the stretch could be undesirable for what I'm trying to do because it may move the intersection of the curves. br2 is already in "inverse function" form. But this is not a problem with the answer.) Then `path1` applies `br1` to `p`. I do not understand why, but I trust the `Evaluate` in the plot is necessary.

Comment: @Sander, we are rescaling the _argument _ (w)  of `br2[w]` , `w` and `pi2opt[w]` to run from `c1`, to `β*q1` as  `w` varies from `c2`, to `β*q2`. Removed `Evaluate` as it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: I am learning a lot of plotting from this answer: `ConditionalExpression`,`BoxRange`. The axis labelling and `PlotStyle` have some advanced commands I do not yet understand.